# joining 2 tables on OR clause

Tags: sql

I am running this query in mysql and it does not complete even after waiting for several hours.

```
select * 
from merged as rm
inner join client_Master as E on E.Code = rm.Code
inner join client_loan_details as d on  (d.Loan_Account = rm.loanacno  or rm.savingacno = d.SavingAccount) and d.id = E.id
group by rm.client_name;
```

Since rows in the tables (merged and client_loan_details) are 10 million, it will take time. I have checked that mysql is using correct indexes and that should not be a problem. But I wonder if my query is correct.
I am joining table rm with d and table E is an intermediate table. Is the query correct as per SQL standards or am I missing something?

Comment: is intermediate table necessary?

Comment: Please include the query plan also

Comment: @marshalcraft  intermediate table is necessary to get the id of client. I have also tried using 2 queries for each set (Client_Master + Client_details = intermediate and then merged + intermediate) and that too takes time. It must be only because of large number of rows. Right?

Comment: It is hard to optimize your query if you don't describe your indexes and do not show your query plan. However, `Select *` is a bad habit and you should avoid it.

Comment: `Select * ` gets you every column from each of the three tables used.Try to specify your columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had bad performance on `OR` in joins as well. Try to take that out of the join. Your `GROUP BY` statement without any aggregates is doing a `DISTINCT`, but only on one column, while you select them all. To me that seems useless.

```
select * 
from merged as rm
inner join client_Master as E on E.Code = rm.Code
inner join client_loan_details as d on d.id = E.id
WHERE (d.Loan_Account = rm.loanacno or rm.savingacno = d.SavingAccount)
```